# Proving that an integral is less than or greater than a number

Tags: calculus

So, I need to show that $1 \leq$ $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+x^3}$ $dx \leq 1.25$.

I mean I could try to say something like since $f'(x) \geq 0$ at $[0,1]$, LHRS is an underestimate. So, with $n= 1$, $ 1f(0) = 1 \leq \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+x^3}$ $dx$. But then I would be stuck with 1.25

But I know there should be a better way, as there are tons of these kinds of questions - involving different functions where using LHRS and RHRS would be a bit complicated.

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $0\leq x \leq 1,$ you have

$$1\leq \sqrt{1+x^3} \leq \sqrt{1+x}.$$

Enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier way is to simply use the monotony of the integral. You already are on the right tracks for the lower bound so let me give you a hint for the upper bound.

You should observe that on $[1,\infty)$ we have $ \sqrt {x} \leq x$ and that your function has values above $1$ over the integration interval.

Comment: Yes this is what you want to do here

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^3}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left(1+\frac{x^3}{2}\right)\,dx = 1+\frac{1}{8}.$$